# How to restore Ubuntu GNU GRUB screen?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my system along with Windows 10 as dual boot. The Ubuntu worked fine for few days, but last day there there were some updates in UBUNTU which I allowed to download and install. During that, my Ubuntu freeze with no mouse and keyboard working, so ultimately I had to force shutdown the system holding power key.
During next boot to the system, the system automatically got booted to Windows 10 with no GNU GRUB Boot loader missing. I tried few solutions from web, but nothing worked for me. I'll post details of solutions I already tried.
I tried boot repair using temporary booting of Ubuntu using flash drive but it also got failed and resulted in **dpkg** error.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

The error is *dpkg-error detected. Please open a terminal then type*

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda12" dpkg --configure -a
```

On typing this command on terminal, error is

```
chroot:failed to run command
```

Is there any possible solution to restore Ubuntu without loosing data.

I tried removing Ubuntu from my machine with fixing Windows boot loader from CMD in Windows Recovery mode, but it's also showing ***Access Denied*** using **bootrec /fixboot** command.

Currently Windows is working fine on system but it's taking time to load up as I messed with boot settings by installing Ubuntu.

Any possible method to restore Ubuntu?
If not, how to fix my Windows System, so that I can install Ubuntu again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) and [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Ubuntu CD (Recommended)

Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.

1. Install and run Boot-Repair
2. Click "Recommended Repair".
3. Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear.
4. If it does not,hold Left Shift while booting.
   You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

For further help see
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows.

Comment: OP says *I tried boot repair using temporary booting of Ubuntu using flash drive but it also got failed and resulted in dpkg error.* So, I guess he had already tried this.